# Crossfilter + dc.js DataTable not sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, datatable, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using a basic dc.js DataTable with my CrossFilter data and trying to sort it via my Value attribute which is a number but I am getting odd ordering of the data.

Here is a JSFiddle showing the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/DonalRafferty83/97mwyp0u/4/

I set up my CrossFilter dimensions as follows:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.InDate);
    d.Value = parseFloat(d.Value).toFixed(2);
});

var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
var typeDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Type;});
```

And then I create the DataTable as follows:

```
var datatable   = dc.dataTable("#dc-data-table");
datatable
    .dimension(dateDim)
    .group(function(d) {return "";})
    .size(data.length)
    // dynamic columns creation using an array of closures
    .columns([
        function(d) { return d.Id; },
        function(d) {return d.Indate;},
        function(d) {return d.Type;},
        function(d) {return d.Category;},
        function(d) {return d.Value;}
    ]).sortBy(function(d) {
        return d.Value;
    })
    .order(d3.descending);
```

Here is what the ordering comes out like, as you can 99 is ordered before 4000.46 which is incorrect:

[image: Incorrect ordering]

Is this a known issue with CrossDilter/dc.js? Or is there something I am doing wrong? Maybe I need to manipulate my data to make it work as in the correct manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.toFixed(2)` returns a string, and as such your sortBy function is sorting a string. Therefore it is correct that "99" is ordered before "4000.46". Switching your sortBy function to `return +d.Value;` (the + forces a conversion back to a number) should fix your problem.

A fixed version of the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j9adz6bs/

Comment: Thanks Ethan, shocking that I missed that! It is working however in my real dataset which is over 100k records large a small value sneaks in at the top of the table, for example 1.9 appears at the top of the table and then the value is sorted correctly , so its 1.9 then 4000 then 3904 and so on, I can't reproduce it with fake data so its a long shot but just wondering if you might have seen something like that before and know of a fix?

Comment: Do you ever have null/undefined in your date dimension? This sounds like the kind of thing that can happen when a crossfilter dimension value isn't naturally ordered.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look through the data to see if there is something like that in there